# add a new counter based on an existing counter in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series that look like this

```
   col
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   1
5   2
6   3
7   1
8   2
9   3
10  1
11  2
```

and I would like to generate a second counter that looks like this

```
   col  col2
0   1     1
1   2     1
2   3     1
3   4     1
4   1     2
5   2     2
6   3     2
7   1     3
8   2     3
9   3     3
10  1     4
11  2     4
```

How can I do that in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `1` is always start of groups then create mask by compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and then add [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for cumulative sum:

```
df['col2'] = df['col'].eq(1).cumsum()
print (df)
    col  col2
0     1     1
1     2     1
2     3     1
3     4     1
4     1     2
5     2     2
6     3     2
7     1     3
8     2     3
9     3     3
10    1     4
11    2     4
```